# Why negative marks?

Tags: support

Can anyone explain this ?   I got so many marks from this question and all of a sudden it gets me negative marks.  How come?   [How accepted is ‘f***ing’ in informal conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144104/how-accepted-is-fing-in-informal-conversation)

Comment: You received ONE downvote and two upvotes when I view how the votes are split. That's not so bad, but to say you got so many "marks" —presumably upvotes, is quite misleading. Everyone has experienced inexplicable downvotes sometime or other in their history, it's only when they are repeated continuously then it is a problem, see posts on serial downvotes. This one explains the phenomena http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/how-to-act-when-you-are-being-serial-downvoted

Comment: and this one http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/557/whats-with-all-the-serial-down-voting-on-the-boobs-question?rq=1

Comment: @Mari-LouA, what I menan is that when I look at my reputation table, I used to have some 10 or 15 marks on this question and, all of a sudden, it dropped to minus 2.

Comment: One upvote per answer is equivalent to ten *marks*. One upvote **per question** is "five points", one downvote per question or answer is minus 2 points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation table shows **recent changes in reputation.** The question has received two upvotes, which gives a +10 in the table (five rep for each upvote); the single downvote would give a −2 in the table because a downvote subtracts 2 from your rep score.

The reputation table does not show the resultant (total) rep for a question.

Here's an example, which happens to be mine:

[image: Reputation chart]

The first answer is shown as −2, but all that means is that someone downvoted it, its [current score](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139073/meaning-of-if-gold-rust-what-shall-the-iron-do/139081#139081) is +2 votes, made up of +3/−1, so it's gained me 28 rep points.

The second answer is shown as +10 because it received an upvote. Its [current score](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110442/the-cheaper-the-car-the-easier-to-buy-it/110449#110449) is +2 with no downvotes, so it's gained me 20 rep points in total.

There's a [help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) explaining how reputation works.